# Spring MVC - No mapping found for HTTP request (for resources)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc

In eclipse I've the [following Spring MVC project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytj5F.png), but when I run on server, I've problem on the load of resources (images, CSS, js...).
I've added `mvc:resources mapping`, but when I run jsp, eclipse tell me:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI `[/ProgettoTecWeb/<c:url value=]` in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispacciatore'

Have you got any solution? Thank's!

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Talent Show</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispacciatore</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispacciatore</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispacciatore-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">     <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="it.uniparthenope"/>
    <!-- Vado a settare il package dove andrò a mettere la mia classe java
    che farà da home Controller. -->            
   <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
      <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**index.jsp** (How call the resources)

```
<link href="<c:url value='/resources/assets/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
...
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/assets/js/custom.js"/>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in calling the resources from index.jsp. That might also be the issue

**Pay attention to the quotes**:

You are currently calling like this

```
<link href="<c:url value='/resources/assets/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Instead of

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/assets/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

See if it Helps.
*You can actually give the path without jstl tags , it works just fine in spring*

Comment: You can actually give the path without jstl tags , it works just fine in spring

Answer (score 0):

You need to create package for Controller class, use annotation RequestMapping to wire to http mapping. Finally, use component scan to point to that particular Controller package. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Project -> Build path -> configure build path -> add server runtime
2. Change your java version running to newest
3. Windown -> show view -> problem -> quick fix all problem